# HTML Link with page building info in it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make an html page for product sales. I want the html link to serve as the page's source of data gathering product title, price, and secondary link from within the original link.

Example: http://www.listprice.us/genericpage.html&amazon&kindle-fire-hd-best-family-kids-tablet&B00CU0NSCU&68.50

The link leads to a generic page on my website that notes, the store, page name, price, and assembles it into a product page. I think i can do most of this, except the data grab from the link itself, which i've tokenized with & above. What is the correct format to put page source data into the link itself? And how do I using whatever method you prefer grab that data on the generic page, so one page may server as an add to cart page for many products? i prefer: html, javascript, or php

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're looking for is to build a query string. The query string starts with `?` and key/value pairs are separated by `&`. Those same pairs follow this format: `key=value`.

Here's what that would look like given your link:

http://www.listprice.us/genericpage.html?store=amazon&product=kindle-fire-hd-best-family-kids-tablet&sku=B00CU0NSCU&price=68.50

The query string is available to JavaScript via `window.location.search` ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)) and php can access the query string via the super global `$_GET` variable ([read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php))